# Urdu in latex (bold font)

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{arabxetex}

\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Kasheeda}

\begin{document}

\begin{urdu}

مندرجہ ذیل مساوات کو حل کریں $x_2 + m$ 

\end{urdu}

$x^2 + m$

\end{document}
```

I am running this program it works fine but the mathematical part is not shown properly within the `\begin{urdu} ... \end{urdu}` section, along with it i can't get the bold font while using the command `\textbf` and if someone suggests me using `polyglossia` then please provide me with an example :)

Comment: Should the title be `Urdu in XeTeX (bold font)` instead of `Urdu in latex (bold font)`?

Answer (score 6):

The font you're using has no bold variant, as far as I can see. Using `polyglossia` is rather easy:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{urdu}

\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq Kasheeda}

\begin{document}

مندرجہ ذیل مساوات کو حل کریں \quad $x^2 + m$ 

$x^2 + m$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: getting fontspec error on \urdufont line

Comment: @FarazAhmad You have to use a font supporting Urdu you have on your system.